# Volume of an $n$-simplex

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In *Multivariable Calculus with Applications* by Lax and Terrell, it gives the following definition of a simplex:

> Let $k\leq n$ and let $\boldsymbol{V}_1,...,\boldsymbol{V}_k$ be linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. A $k$-simplex with vertices $\boldsymbol{0},\boldsymbol{V}_1,...,\boldsymbol{V}_k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the set of all points
> $$\boldsymbol{X} = c_1\boldsymbol{V}_1 +c_2\boldsymbol{V}_2 +···+c_k\boldsymbol{V}_k \text{ where } 0 \leq c_i \text{ and } \sum^{k}_{i=1}c_i \leq 1.$$

I am unsure about why the following definition is a sensible one:

> The volume of an $n$-simplex is defined to be the product of the ($n$ − 1)-dimensional volume of the $j$-face times the distance from $\boldsymbol{V}_j$ to the hyperplane spanned by the $\boldsymbol{V}_i$,($i\neq j$) that contains the $j$-face, divided by $n$.

I can see why this would be the case when $n=2$, as it's just the area of a right-angled triangle. I think the idea might be that one can can fit $n$ of the $n$-simplices into a parallelepiped spanned by the same vectors, but I can't get my head around it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The $n=2$ case isn't "just the area of a right-angled triangle"; it's the area of *any* triangle. The definition is a bit wordy, but all it's saying that volume is "$\frac1n\cdot \text{base} \cdot \text{height}$" ... where the "$\text{base}$" is an $(n-1)$-dimensional simplex and the "$\text{height}$" is the perpendicular distance to that simplex from the remaining vertex. This generalizes the area of a (not-necessarily-right) triangle $\triangle ABC$ as $\frac12|AB|\cdot(\text{dist to $C$})$ and the volume of tetrahedron $ABCD$ as $\frac13|ABC|\cdot(\text{dist to $D$}$).

Comment: Thank you for the response. That was a mistake on my part about the "right-angle".  I can see what you're saying about base⋅height, but I'm still unsure as to why we have the $\frac{1}{n}$ factor.


In the $n=2$ case we're dividing the base⋅height by $2$ because the triangle fits into the parallelogram twice. I think this extends to higher dimensions, but I can't see why.